After Ubuntu Installation: Touchpad Inconsistency, System Restart Failure, and Keyboard Unresponsiveness"
When I installed Ubuntu 22.04, not only is my touchpad not working consistently, but also I'm unable to restart the system when encountering these issues. Occasionally, even the keyboard fails to respond. Has anyone else faced this situation? How did you troubleshoot it, especially when the usual remedy of restarting the system isn't an option? Any insights or suggestions would be invaluable.

It's Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
